# ¿Cómo puedo en android encriptar el IMEI en MD5?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

necesito `encriptar` el `IMEI` en `MD5`, alguien sabe como se haría ? yo logro obtener el `IMEI` pero para la `encriptación`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No encriptas a `MD5`, lo que haces es **hashear** a `MD5`. Puedes hacerlo con `MessageDigest`:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
md.update(imei.getBytes("UTF-8"));
byte[] digest = md.digest();
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, digest);
// para tratar con el padding
String md5 = String.format("%0" + (digest.length << 1) + "x", bi);
```

Creo que `MessageDigest#getInstance` lanza una `NoSuchAlgorithmException` si se intenta obtener un algoritmo de hasheado inexistente, así que tendrás que hacer un try catch.

Answer (score 4):

Para obtener el **MD5** del **IMEI**, te comparto un método mediante el uso de la clase    **[MessageDigest](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/MessageDigest.html)** :

#### Método para generar código MD5 de una cadena en Android :

```
    private String getMD5(final String s) {
            try{
                MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                digest.update(s.getBytes());
                byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();
                StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
                for(int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++){
                    String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
                    while(h.length() < 2){
                        h = "0" + h;
                    }
                    hexString.append(h);
                }
                return hexString.toString();
            }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
                Log.e("MD5", "md5() NoSuchAlgorithmException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return "";
        }
```

lo puedes llamar de esta forma para obtener el MD5 (es hash no encriptación de la cadena) de tu IMEI:

```
String myIMEI_MD5 = getMD5(myIMEI);
```

Para [obtener el IMEI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8145184/250260) de tu dispositivo esta seria la forma usando la clase [TelephonyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html):

```
String myIMEI = "";
        TelephonyManager mTelephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (mTelephony.getDeviceId() != null){
            myIMEI = mTelephony.getDeviceId(); 
        }
```

Otro **método** el cual es el **recomendado** mediante [Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html) , el cual obtiene  un ID como una cadena única  64 bits hexadecimal.

```
String myIMEI = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

recuerda agregar el permiso en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Otro método para obtener el `md5` de una cadena.

Adaptando el código con las sugerencias de Android Studio 2.1

```
public static String getMD5(String s) {
    try {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(s.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte aMessageDigest : messageDigest)
            hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & aMessageDigest));
        return hexString.toString();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

**Su uso**

```
getMD5("número imei");
```