# ¿Cómo capturar el imei de un dispositivo en Android, API 23?

Tags: java, android

tengo el siguiente código, pero he hecho las pruebas correspondientes en distintos celulares y el problema solo se genera en dispositivos con android 6.0

```
    private String obtenerImei() {
        //StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        //.append()
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        String imei =tm.getDeviceId(); // Obtiene el imei  or  "352319065579474";
        return imei;
        //TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        //mngr.getDeviceId();
    }
```

Comment: Puedes tener la respuesta en http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/14917/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-en-android-encriptar-el-imei-en-md5

Comment: es el mismo código que tengo, y no me ha funcionado. supongo que es por la  versión del api

Comment: Puede ser que sea cosa de los permisos, en Android 6.0 tienes que pedirlos en runtime ademas del manifest. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @ICRUZ si usas Android 6.0 como menciona WebServeis debes requerir los permisos, agregue en mi respuesta la forma de realizarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Esto fue respondido anteriormente,
Para [obtener el IMEI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8145184/250260) de tu dispositivo esta seria la forma usando la clase [TelephonyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html):

```
String myIMEI = "";
        TelephonyManager mTelephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (mTelephony.getDeviceId() != null){
            myIMEI = mTelephony.getDeviceId(); 
        }
```

Otro **método** el cual es el **recomendado** mediante [Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html) , el cual obtiene  un ID como una cadena única  64 bits hexadecimal.

```
String myIMEI = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

recuerda agregar el permiso en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

En Android 6.0 se requiere pedir permiso de esta forma:

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE );
if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso.");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE }, 225);
} else {
    Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que añadir esto al android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Y por si tambien quieres obtener el id del telefono

```
String deviceId = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Espero que te sirva